# Enabling Disabled tools in the visual studio toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I am developing my minor and major project in VS2008. Suddenly tools have started to go missing from my toolbar. I have visited several forums but am not able to solve the problem.

Basically I have silverlight 2.0 installed with SDK, and tools and all.
Now when I need to access the media element control from silverlight it does not display.
Further more on listing all controls I can see those controls but they are disabled.

Please Help Me out.

Regards
Shrey Mishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird but I was able to solve the problem by simply removing USB Mouse .:)

When i checked this out with some others developing on their laptops it came to me that it happens with very few of us in VS 2008 but still can drive on mad.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

1. Reset all setting in tools -> Import and Export Setting menu

Or

2 You should update your VS 2008 SP1 with . NET 3.5

Hope this help,

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but it has something to do with the references in the project. I have the same problem with some of my projects when i started adding references to many assemblies.

When you reset the toolbox ,does it work ? On my computer, whenever I reset the toolbox, the icons come back only to disappear some time later after rebuilding the application many times.

Icons should not disappear from anywhere other than your toolbox.

Comment: sir ,
i have already reinstalled vs-2008 ,and also deleted the temp files .
Its wierd but i was able to solve the problem by simply removing USB Mouse .:) 
Thanks And Regards

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem:
Reset all setting in `Tools -> Import and Export Setting` menu

helped nicely))